# Get homepage URL of applications user has access to from Microsoft Azure AD via Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

My goal: get applications user has access to and their homepage URL's from Microsoft Azure AD graph API.

Using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/approleassignment I can see what applications the user is a user of (HTTP GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/appRoleAssignments). But the resulting data does not have the application ID, so I can't get the app details via the /applications/(appID) endpoint https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-get (HTTP GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/).

How do I get the application details of applications the user (who is logged in) is a user of?

I queried the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/approleassignment endpoint then tried feeding it's data to the applications endpoint, and none of the ID values from the rolesassignment endpoint resulted in a successful request or matched with the numbers in the portal.azure.com page of the apps.

Edit: I see the resourceID matches the object ID in the azure portal now. But, when I do a query to graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications / {ObjectID} { "code": "Request_ResourceNotFound", "message": "Resource '{ObjectID}' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.", "innerError": { "date": "2023-07-12T14:36:44", "request-id": "", "client-request-id": "" } } I put the  messages. Is my query right? Is this a permissions thing?

Comment: Check the resourceId property in app role assignment. This is the id of the service principal. Using this, you can get the application details.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment. I see the resourceID matches the object ID in the azure portal now. But, when I do a query to 

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications / {ObjectID}

{
    "code": "Request_ResourceNotFound",
    "message": "Resource '{ObjectID}' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.",
    "innerError": {
        "date": "2023-07-12T14:36:44",
        "request-id": "<REMOVED>",
        "client-request-id": "<REMOVED>"
    }
}

I put the <removed> messages. 

Is my query right? Is this a permissions thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the application home page URL from app role assignments, it's going to be a multi-step procedure.

First, get the `resourceId` property from the app role assignment. This is going to be the service principal id.

Then you would need to get the details of the service principal using [`Get servicePrincipal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) operation. Look for `appId` property in the service principal details. This is the id of the application.

Once you have the application id, you would then get the details of the application using [`Get application`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) and from there you can get the home page URL.